# Android Studio não abre novo projeto (fica transpatente)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

quando instalei e tentei abrir pela primeira vez, funcionou perfeitamente, porem, quando tentei abrir novamente depois, quando clico em "Start a new Android Studio project", a janela abre, mas fica transparente eternamente (como pode ver na imagem). não da nenhum alerta de erro, arquivos faltando, nada.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

depois que tive este bug, eu tendei:

- atualizar todas ferramentas e SDKs
- rodar como ADM
- rodar o programa sem nenhum outro programa aberto pra ter mais potencia do pc
- adicionar a variável de sistema "JAVA_HOME" com as
  localizações dos JDKs e JREs
- instalar ferramentas SDK (SDK tools) individuais
- desinstalar e reinstalar todos JREs, JDKs e o Android Studio
- mudar as versões dos JREs e JDKs para outras mais antigas
- procurei os requisitos mínimos pra rodar o programa (que você pode ver aqui: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

  e acho que meu pc roda (ele tem 4gb RAM, 150gb de espaço livre no HD onde esta instalado o programa, processador AMD Sempron 145 2.8ghz, win 7 32-bit, resolução de tela de 1280x1024px, e todos JREs, JDKs e SDKs necessários)
- ontem eu tentei mudar a localização da instalação pra outro HD, e na minha ultima tentativa, eu voltei o pc com uma restauração de sistema, pra 4 dias antes da primeira instalação, nada disso resolveu

alguém sabe o que posso fazer pra resolver isso? se não, existe algum outro programa que possa usar no lugar no Android Studio? sou novato no desenvolvimento para android, eu realmente preciso muito muito de ajuda. 
Desculpe o post gigante, só estou tentando ser o mais específico possível.

Obrigado desde já, tenha um bom dia.

Comment: Depois disso tudo, eu formataria.

Comment: pois é amigo, estou começando a considerar essa ideia :(

Comment: Pode ser o sistema operacional amigo.

Comment: Acho difícil, o win 7 não costuma dar problema com nada :/

Comment: Verifica o log do Android Studio (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519)

Comment: tente executar em modo de compatibilidade....talvez funcione

Answer (score 1):

Já tive um problema parecido, só consegui resolver formatando a maquina, nem mesmo pegando ma versão beta do AS resolveu. Recomendo fazer isso. da menos dor de cabeça.

(Esse problema aconteceu comigo quando usava android studio e  Eclipse com ADT na mesma maquina, não sei se tem alguma ligação, Também tinha outros ambientes com cordova, ionic framework)

Comment: Ah sim, okay então, bem, essa vai ser uma ideia que vai dar bastante trabalho, pois nem o CD pra fazer isso eu tenho mais haha por isso estou deixando essa ideia por último. Acho que se for pra formatar é melhor eu caçar algum outro programa pra usar no lugar do AS, eu tenho o eclipse também, mas eu já tinha aquela primeira vez que abriu e funcionou :/ isso que estranhei.